# How to get appropriate scaled image from graphic rectangle

Tags: plotting, image

I am trying to make an image out of a graphic, which is a rectangle with given size.

However, the dimension of the image do not correspond to the size given to the rectangle:

```
im = Image[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 20}]]];
ImageDimensions[im]
```

> {221, 432}

Anyone knows how to do it ?

Comment: `im = Image[ Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 20}], ImageSize -> {10, 20}]]`?

Comment: @kglr thanks ! This works. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very beautiful, but working:

```
 im = ImageResize[Image[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}]]], {10, 20}];
```

Comment: Works ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
im = Image[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 20}]], ImageSize -> {10, 20}]; (* or *)
im = Image[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 20}], ImageSize -> {10, 20}]];

ImageDimensions[im]
```

> {10, 20}